# AttributeError: module 'torch.optim' has no attribute 'RMSProp'

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

Getting the following error when trying to use the RMSProp Optimizer with PyTorch:

```
AttributeError: module 'torch.optim' has no attribute 'RMSProp'
```

Code:

```py
import torch as T
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class DeepQNetwork(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, alpha, ...):
    super(DeepQNetwork, self).__init__()
    ...
    self.optimizer = optim.RMSProp(self.parameters(), lr=alpha)
    ...
```

PyTorch version is `1.5.1` with Python version `3.6`. There's a documentation for `torch.optim` and its optimizers including [RMSProp](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.RMSprop), but PyCharm only suggests Adam and SGD and it really seems like all other optimizers are missing.

Does anyone have an idea? I did not find a single thing on the internet and it starts driving me crazy.

[Suggesstion from PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgYBU.png)

Comment: Does python throw an error when you run the code?

Comment: Python throws the AttributeError stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RMSprop` (as seen in the documentation) instead of `RMSProp`. So, it's just a typo.

Comment: Thanks, was so confused that PyCharm only suggested Adam and SGD that I did not notice the typo.